# An exponent operator affiliated to a vN algebra.

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-field-theory, unitary-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

To begin with I introduce the basic elements of my question.

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a real Hilbert space, for each $f\in \mathcal{K}$ there is a densily defined selfadjoint operator $\varphi(f)$ on a Hilbert space $\mathfrak{F}$, also $\varphi(tf)=t\varphi(f)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. So for $f\in \mathcal{K}$,  $e^{i\varphi(f)}$ are unitary operators (bounded).

Then $R(\mathcal{K}):= \{ e^{i\varphi(f)} / f\in \mathcal{K} \}''$ is a Von Neumann algebra.

Lastly, for a fix $f\in \mathcal{K}$ the map $U:\mathbb{R}\to R(\mathcal{K})$ given by $U(t)=e^{i\varphi(tf)}$ is strongly and also weak continuous.

In order to see that $\varphi(f) \eta R(\mathcal{K})$ (is afiliated to) I did the folowing.

Any $A\in R(\mathcal{K})'$ satisfies $AU(t)=U(t)A$, and by deriving this at $t=0$ we have $A\varphi(f)=\varphi(f)A$ in the common domain, i.e. $\varphi(f) \eta R(\mathcal{K})$.

**(1) Is the above argument right?**

My last question is about the following chain of equalities,

**(2) I'm taking limits of elements in $R(\mathcal{K})$, wich is (weak and strongly) closed, so I conclude that $\varphi(f)\in R(\mathcal{K})$, but this is wrong, because $\varphi(f)$ is not bouded. What is the mistake?**

$\varphi(f)=w-\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{U(t)-U(0)}{it}$

Comment: The limit $\frac{U(t)-U(0)}{it}$ as $t\to0$ is not a strong or weak limit in the usual sense, since it will only converge strongly or weakly within the domain $D(A)$.

Comment: Many thanks s.harp, I assumed it was.

Comment: But I have another question. You mean $D(\varphi(f))$ instead of $D(A)$? because $A$ is an element of a von Neumann algebra so is bounded. I understand the mistake in (2), but (1) is right, isn't it?

Comment: Right, yes $D(\varphi(f))$. The argument in (1) is only conditionally correct. Taking the derivative of $U(t)$ is indeed the step to show that $\varphi(f)$ is associated to $R$, but the actual details are missing. This is fine if you feel comfortable backing up the claim with a formal proof, if you do not know how to carry it out then it is insufficient.